# Proper way to build interogative conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

Suppose we have this sentence:

- If I hadn't met her two years ago we wouln't be married today. *(I wonder if marrying is possible?)*

What's the best way to ask that?

- Would you be married today hadn't you met her two years ago?
- If you hadn't met her two years ago would you be married today?

Comment: Might I recommend the use of commas after "ago"... it's often quite helpful as it's a natural place to pause. I think it's an "optional" comma but it's generally useful.

Comment: "Had you not met" would be a clearer, more natural construction than "had not you met".  Your second example is a much better way to organize the sentence, and more natural.

Comment: I'd set the comma in the second question, too, but using the comma in the first question would be ambiguous, because then the sentence would look like two questions in a row. Obviously two question marks should be used instead, or a semicolon. But I think, this shows why the second question using the *if* is clearer. The order of the clauses doesn't matter much, because the sentence is short enough, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with Hector.  I think I was just reacting to the choice of "if" rather than "had" in my earlier comment.

Comment: "if you hadn't met..." or "had you not met"

Comment: The **would you be married today...** form makes it sound as though the two-year part is important, e.g. because you were engaged to someone else at the time who then died or ran away to Ulaanbaatar before the wedding.  For some reason, that's not also true of the **if you hadn't...** form, so that's the better of the two.

Comment: Of course you would not have married her if you had not met. I think you need to add a reason that makes meeting a special case. Had you not been on that ferry two years ago, you may not be married today.

Comment: @Willow:  to be fair, the "you" in "you be married" might be singular rather than plural.

Comment: @MMacD forgive me but have no clue what you mean. Isn't the *you* singular? I certainly thought it was in  my example. I'm really bad with grammar, so I am asking honestly.

Comment: @Willow, whether it's singular or plural can only be determined from context (I can't offhand think of an IE language where that's not true, though I'm tired at the mo, so perhaps there are dozens), and in this case the context is ambiguous.  It's certainly singular in the first clause, but the second one can be read **"...would you [two] be married today?"** as well as **"...would you [yourself] be married [to someone else] today?"**

Comment: @MMacD Thank you, now I get what you mean. I meant the singular 'you', and my own brain fart did not allow for the *understood* 'two'.

Comment: @Willow  I was being a little unfair to you even while claiming to be fair:  since the first "you" was certainly singular, the "nearest antecedent"  rule would make the second one singular too.  But everyone seems to ignore number change in "you", possibly because it still "looks okay" even when it's been transformed into a verbal rake in the grass.

Comment: @MMacD I am here to learn and that is truly my goal. I did not feel you were unfair, but I also did not understand. No worries and thank you.